# Add Event Handler to Next button in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, inputfield, lightning-recordeditform

Having some trouble validating an Aura component field (it allows lookup in Flow) as i can't seem to think of how to fire an onclick event from the standard Next button (in flow). I would use the onclick event to validate whether the field was empty or not.

I am using lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:input field in my Aura component. I am trying to integrate the validation mentioned in [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm)

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="First name" placeholder="First name" required="true" />
    <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="Last name" placeholder="Last name" required="true" />        
    <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.onClick }" />
```

```
({
onClick: function (cmp, evt, helper) {
    var allValid = cmp.find('field').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
     }, true);
     if (allValid) {
         alert('All form entries look valid. Ready to submit!');
     } else {
         alert('Please update the invalid form entries and try again.');
     }
 }
```

})

As you can see this example requires a Submit button in order to fire the validation (which makes sense). Does anyone have any ideas on how i would access the Next button in the flow in order to add an onclick event?

Comment: please include the relevant code from your link

Comment: good point, added